# How to add a legend and labels to the pie chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How can I add a legend on top of 3 pie charts (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ja08wyra/55/)).

I want to specify that the light blue color corresponds to the legend "AAA", medium  blue is "BBB" and blue is "CCC".

Also I would like to add numeric values inside each piece of pie. I tried this approach, but then the charts disappear:

```
var data = [
  [{"piece_value",76.34}, {"piece_value",69.05}, {"piece_value",275.19}],
  [{"piece_value",69.93}, {"piece_value",61.50}, {"piece_value",153.31}],
  [{"piece_value",83.51}, {"piece_value",69.14}, {"piece_value",204.32}]
];

svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) { return d.piece_value; }))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(r / 2)
        .outerRadius(r))
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });
```

UPDATE:

I also tried this, but the same result:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.piece_value; });

svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(r / 2)
        .outerRadius(r))
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });
```

Comment: Are you looking for specific code samples or just for some ideas?
You can add a legend by declaratively adding svg <g> group tag and positioning it in the <svg> element or even better, just use regular html tags and style them accordingly. It will be easier to position the html tags.

Comment: @codeepic: I have little experience with d3 and JavaScript. Therefore I am looking for a concrete code piece in the fiddle that I posted. Also I would appreciate detailed comments of the corresponding changes in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your data array. This:

```
{"piece_value",76.34}
```

Is not a proper object. It should have a colon between the name and the value:

```
{"piece_value": 76.34}
```

So, let's change your data for this:

```
var data = [
    [{"piece_value":76.34, name:"AAA"}, {"piece_value":69.05, name:"BBB"}, {"piece_value":275.19, name:"CCC"}],
    [{"piece_value":69.93, name:"AAA"}, {"piece_value":61.50, name:"BBB"}, {"piece_value":153.31, name:"CCC"}],
    [{"piece_value":83.51, name:"AAA"}, {"piece_value":69.14, name:"BBB"}, {"piece_value":204.32, name:"CCC"}]
];
```

And set the variables for the layout and the arc generator:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.piece_value;
    });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(r / 2)
    .outerRadius(r);
```

For adding the values in each pie, you can use `arc.centroid`:

```
svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(pie)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")")
    .text(d => d.data.piece_value);
```

For creating the legend, add the rectangles and the texts using the inner arrays:

```
svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(d => d)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [
    [{
        "piece_value": 76.34,
        name: "AAA"
    }, {
        "piece_value": 69.05,
        name: "BBB"
    }, {
        "piece_value": 275.19,
        name: "CCC"
    }],
    [{
        "piece_value": 69.93,
        name: "AAA"
    }, {
        "piece_value": 61.50,
        name: "BBB"
    }, {
        "piece_value": 153.31,
        name: "CCC"
    }],
    [{
        "piece_value": 83.51,
        name: "AAA"
    }, {
        "piece_value": 69.14,
        name: "BBB"
    }, {
        "piece_value": 204.32,
        name: "CCC"
    }]
];

var m = 10,
    r = 100,
    z = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", (r + m) * 2)
    .attr("height", (r + m) * 2)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (r + m) + "," + (r + m) + ")");

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.piece_value;
    });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(r / 2.2)
    .outerRadius(r/1.2)

svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return z(i);
    });

svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(pie)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")")
    .text(d => d.data.piece_value);
  
svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(d=>d)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
  .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate(" + (-r + 2.5*m + (i * 70)) + "," +  (-r + m) + ")")
  .text(d=>d.name);
  
svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(d=>d)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
  .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate(" + (-r + m + (i * 70)) + "," +  (-r) + ")")
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill", (d, i) => z(i));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This perfectly solves the second part of my question. As to the legend, I want to see a horizontal legend on top of all pie charts, syaing something like "light blue color - AAA", "blue color - BBB", "dark blue color - CCC" (of course, light blue etc should be substituted by a small rectangle with the corresponding color).